# In Flutter How can I use my sign in Page to directly update the app drawer details?

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I use my sign in Page to directly update the app drawer details?
Problems i am facing right now is that. 
I have a sign in function and 2 classes. 
1 that displays app drawer and 1 for login page which calls signinFunction. 
Now I am not able to get where to place that sign in function. 
if i make that global then it was unable to use setState function. 
if i put that in appDrawer class. 
i am unable to call my signin function from another class

Comment: Please be clearer, what are you trying to update from the sign in page to your drawer, and include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand you problem, did you try to use a `StreamController` to send event between your widgets ?

```
 // global or common parent widget
 final controller = new StreamController<MyEvent>();

 // widget A
 controller.add(new MyEvent());
 controller.close(); // on dispose

 // widget B
 final subscription = controller.listen((event) { setState(() {}); });
 subscription.cancel(); // on dispose
```